# Calling Rest API from a markdown template

Tags: rest, markdown

Is it possible to make a call to a rest api and process the JSON response from it?

There is a requirement I am working on to show the status of different services documented using markdown.
Or if there is a way to run custom javascript code, that will work too.

Comment: Isn't this what all badges on github repos' README.md are doing?

Comment: @moonwave99, no they tend to link to an actual image that the badge provider dynamically generates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF your markdown interpreter supports inline javascript, then maybe. I imagine a lot of markdown interpreters will have this disabled as it's unsafe.

The answer depends both on the markdown interpreter itself (there's no 1 hard standard, and everyone has extensions) and it depends on how its configured.

I would say that it's likely that this will not work, but it might be possible

Comment: appreciate the response. Will give it a try.